# How to keep leading zeros in datetime to string conversion?

Tags: python, datetime

I am facing an issue whenever I try to convert a datetime object into string that has leading zeros in the year

Suppose d is my datetime object:

```
d = '0021-01-12 03:12:28'

d_str = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The output of printing d_str is always (regardless of %Y or %y)

`'21-01-12 03:12:28.000000'`

The desired output should have leading zeros for the year

`'0021-01-12 03:12:28.000000'`

The [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) suggests one of `%y or %Y` format codes should work, however, I have tried both options and they do not work.

Is there a way to do this using the datetime library or do I need to write custom logic?

Comment: The difference between `%Y` and `%y` is that the latter *removes* the century part. But if there's no century part to begin with, it won't be added. You could use ordinary string formatting of `d.year` to print it with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (edited to reflect suggestion in comment)

```
d.strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").zfill(26)
```

Comment: What if the year is > 99 ? Better zero-fill the string to a fixed length.

Comment: You are right that is a better solution. Updating answer.